# What is the Difference Between These Two HTMLCollections?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to collect ratings for all products that have ratings on this page: https://www.theluxelens.com/pages/photoshop-overlays. While I can get the code below to work in my own browser (Chrome), it does not work on the page itself.

It is, however, able to get the elements that have the ratings, because the first console.log statement returns those elements.

```
  var ratingsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("spr-badge");
  console.log(ratingsElements);
  var nonZeroRatings = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < ratingsElements.length ; i++){
    var rating = ratingsElements[i].getAttribute("data-rating");
    console.log(rating);
    if(rating != "0.0") {
      nonZeroRatings.push(rating)
    } 
  }
  console.log("logging the ratings...");
  console.log(nonZeroRatings);
```

There looks like a slight difference in what is returned when the code below is run in my own console vs from the page itself. When run from my browser console, the first console.log statement in my code returns an HTMLCollection that is slightly different - **I believe this difference is why the code isn't working when run from the page itself, but I don't know why it is different.** This code works, as you can see it delivers the ratings of products that have them (non-zero ratings) in an array:

[image: browser console]

VS. when the same code, run from the page, notice the HTMLCollection returned is slightly different:

[image: code from the HTML of the page]

This is the full script tag from the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {

  var ratingsElements = document.getElementsByClassName("spr-badge");
  console.log(ratingsElements);
  var nonZeroRatings = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < ratingsElements.length ; i++){
    var rating = ratingsElements[i].getAttribute("data-rating");
    console.log(rating);
    if(rating != "0.0") {
      nonZeroRatings.push(rating)
    } 
  }
  console.log("logging the ratings...");
  console.log(nonZeroRatings); 
};

</script>
```

Thanks for any insight here. This is a Shopify website, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I guess the content loads after your script runs.

Comment: @James you are correct - I was running my script after page load, but then I realized that the elements that my script was pulling from are also not rendered (by a Shopify script) until page load. So it was working in console but not at page load. I have it working now - thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log something from the page, it basically logs a reference which values are not filled in until the developer goes to look at the console entry. You may notice that little information icon beside it in the log entry, if you hover/click on that it should indicate this to you. Where, as when you're running this from the console it instead decides in this case to pull the collection data right away and log it.

That's the difference between runtime execution and developer intent in the console in some situations. This same concept applies at other times as well, I don't know all of them right off. That information icon showing up is a good indicator of the entry being a reference initially instead of a full data copy.

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that the page elements are not really there yet when my script is running from the page?

Comment: Nope, they're there. The console just isn't polling for the items within that collection until you open the DevTools and ask to see it. That way, the system saves memory for normal users if developers ship this stuff to production (happens way too often.)